# Rails 3.1/Mongoid - How to find model by name rather than id in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

**Edit:** i am using Mongoid/MongoDB for my database, meaning I don't get the normal Active Record tools I think.

I have a simple Rails 3.1 app with a model Page. I would like to match '/:customURL' to the Page#show action for the Page with the relevant :customURL. How should I change the controller and routes? Keep in mind that there are a few routes from '/SOMETHING' that I want to keep. For instance '/pages' should still go to my Page#index action not try to find a page with customURL of 'pages'.

current controller:

```
def show
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
@title = @page.title

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @page }
  end
end
```

routes:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :feeds
end

get "pages/index"
get "pages/show"
get "pages/new"

root :to => "pages#index"
```

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `Page` has a `customURL` attribute from its database table.  In your controller:

```
def show
  @page = Page.first(:conditions => {:customURL => params[:customURL]})
  @title = @page.title

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @page }
  end
end
```

In your routes

```
resources :pages, :except => :show do
  resources :feeds
end

# Anything you want to match before the custom URLs needs to go above the next route definition
get "/:customURL" => "pages#show"    

root :to => "pages#index"
```

Comment: Hey thanks man. I'm getting  NoMethod Error tho. Note that I'm using customURL rather than custom_url but otherwise I put the code in just as you posted. Any thoughts?   `Started GET "/Helloworld" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-10 12:43:20 -0400
  Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"customURL"=>"Helloworld"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by_customURL' for Page:Class):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:16:in `show'`.

Comment: The problem is probably that I'm using mongoid and not the standard active record tools.

Comment: @tuddy what is the name of the database field in which you are storing the custom URL?

Comment: @tuddy Sorry, it just struck me that you are using Mongo, with which I have no experience.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. I think from the routes side this is working, it's just the controller doesn't understand the find methods i'm trying to call on it. the database field is customURL.

Comment: @tuddy From a quick search it looks like you can do something like `Page.first(:conditions => {:customURL => params[:customURL]})`.  Maybe I'll get a bit of time soon to play around with Mongoid.  If you can't figure out how to find the correct page, then you might open an SO question specifically about Mongoid and database queries.  Good luck, and I hope you get this figured out soon.

Comment: yeah, nice. that works. Want to edit your answer to show that? Thanks!